# Copying Worksheets from one Workbook to other

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I am quite new to excel VBA macros so my problem should be easily solved.

I am trying to open all files in one folder, edit those files a little bit and copy them to existing workbook. Unfortunately, run-time error '424': Object required, occurs.

Highlighted is row:

ActiveSheets.Copy After:=Workbooks("Macro sheets.xlsm").Sheets(Sheets.Count)

It looks like "Macro sheets.xlsm", does not exists, but that is the name of workbook, from which I run this macro.

I have went through many forums, tried a lot of codes, but still did not find the solution.

Please, can somebody help me?

Thank you a lot,

Jan

```
Sub nahranidat()

Dim YourFile As Variant
Dim YourFolderPath As Variant
YourFolderPath = "K:\MMR\2015\BO\macro files connection\"
ChDir YourFolderPath
YourFile = Dir(YourFolderPath & "*.*")
Do While YourFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=YourFolderPath & YourFile
    YourFile = Dir
Set myObject = ActiveWindow


If Activeworkbook.Worksheets.Count = 2 Then

Sheets(1).Select
ActiveSheet.Name = Left(Activeworkbook.Name, InStr(Activeworkbook.Name, ".") - 1) & "_1_month"
Sheets(2).Select
ActiveSheet.Name = Left(Activeworkbook.Name, InStr(Activeworkbook.Name, ".") - 1) & "_by_month"


Activeworkbook.Sheets.Select

ActiveSheets.Copy After:=Workbooks("Macro sheets.xlsm").Sheets(Sheets.Count)

Else

Sheets(1).Select
ActiveSheet.Name = Left(Activeworkbook.Name, InStr(Activeworkbook.Name, ".") - 1)

Activeworkbook.Sheets.Select

ActiveSheets.Copy After:=Workbooks("Macro sheets.xlsm").Sheets(Sheets.Count)


End If

Application.CutCopyMode = False
myObject.Close , SaveChanges:=False
Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've referenced ActiveSheets instead of ActiveSheet so VBA will assume you have created a new object. Just change that line to

```
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Workbooks("Macro sheets.xlsm").Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

It is good practice to declare Option Explicit at the top of each module, that way a 'variable not defined' error makes it easier to spot typographical errors in variable/object names. You can set this automatically by going to VBA>Tools>Options>Editor>Require Variable Declaration.

Comment: Hello Dave, thank you very much for your answer. Now the macro works for the part after else- so for Workbooks with one worksheet. Do you have any idea, how to solve the problem with two selected worksheets?

Comment: `If Activeworkbook.Worksheets.Count = 2 Then
    
    Sheets(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Name = Left(Activeworkbook.Name, InStr(Activeworkbook.Name, ".") - 1) & "_1_month"
    
    Sheets(2).Select
    ActiveSheet.Name = Left(Activeworkbook.Name, InStr(Activeworkbook.Name, ".") - 1) & "_by_month"
    
    Activeworkbook.Sheets.Select
    
    'here is the problem:
    
    ActiveSheets.Copy After:=Workbooks("Macro sheets.xlsm").Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    
    'from here it works:
    
    Else`

Comment: It is the reference to Activesheets again. Instead of selecting all sheets then trying to copy them, you can change Activeworkbook.Sheets.Select for Activeworkbook.Sheets.Copy